# Unable to do live preview for brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I have problem with opening brackets and do live preview recently. While launching brackets, it is showing the following info too. Does anyone has any idea?
[image: 1]

Comment: Did you follow the instructions that it's asking you to follow?

Comment: i don't know what does it mean. when i click on the open preference, it is showing a jason file. I don't know what to do with that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of Brackets unable to find PHP 7 runtime in the system path or 'brackets.json'

to fix this:

go to Debug > Open Preferences File and add

```
"php": {
    "enablePhpTooling": true,
    "executablePath": "your path to php.exe",
    "memoryLimit": "4095M",
    "validateOnType": "false" 
}
```

[PHP Support in Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/PHP-Support-in-Brackets)